# docker compose enable ipv4

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose` file.  The services are running, but only listening on IPV6.  I dont really care if IPV6 is enabled, but I also need IPV4 enabled.

I cant seem to enable IPV4. I have attempted to disable IPV6 which would force it to use V4, but no luck.  What options do I have to enable IPV4?  I know I can force it on the host itself, but I don't want to add any config to the host, I would prefer to let Docker handle the config.

```yaml
    version: "3"
    services:
      web:
        image: php:alpine3.12
        restart: unless-stopped
        #environment:
        volumes:
          - web_Data:/var/www/html
        networks:
          app_net:
        ports:
          - 80:80
          - 443:443
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        
      mariadb:
        image: mariadb
        restart: unless-stopped
        environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Password1
        volumes:
          - mariadb_Data:/var/lib/mysql
        networks:
          app_net:
        ports:
          - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      web_Data:
      mariadb_Data:
        driver: local
    
    networks:
      app_net:
        driver: bridge
        enable_ipv6: false
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address

Comment: Can we have some information on the error your getting or the expected behaviour ? What makes you think that ipv4 is not enabled ?

Comment: When I go to the website it doesnt work and netstat -nat tells me it is only listening on IPV6.

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting?  Ignore the `netstat` output: what hostname and port are you trying to connect to, from where, and what error does it produce?  Are there any interesting logs from the containers when they start up?

Comment: Also: in the `docker-compose.yml` file you show, you're mounting a Docker named volume `web_Data` into `/var/www/html` in your container.  How does data get into this named volume?  Do you need a `build:` step that `COPY`s your application code into an image, instead of a volume?